# Update xml file using simple-framework

Tags: java, android, dom, simple-framework

I'm using simple-framework to xml parsing in my android project. Is it possible to update only specified xml element?

I'm getting list of java objects from xml and I would like to update only one (or more) object at a time and write back to this xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to implement this behaviour manually (eg. skipp n bytes then read some xml), but it's easier - and safer - to process the whole xml.

Comment: Thanks for answer, hmm in that case I will stay with whole file processing

Comment: If your problem is solved, please accept the answer.